# How do get rid of Javascript "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a calendar which updates with Javascript, but "undefined" shows up at the bottom and I can't see anything wrong.

Here's the javascript:

```
function calendar(month){
var s= new Date();

var year=s.getFullYear();
var wday= s.getDay();
var mday =s.getDate();


var days = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
 document.write(' <table border=\"1\" bordercolor=\"black\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"220px\"><h6 style="size:.5em;"><tr>\n');


 for (i=0; i<(days.length); i++) {
     document.write(' <td style=\"background-color: #CCCCCC; text-align: center; width: 33px;padding:2px; \"> <strong> ' + days[i] + ' </strong></td> ');
 }
 var day=1;
 b=6;

 for ( count = 0; count < (b*7); count++) {

         var start= new Date(year,month,day,0,0,0,0);

         var dayarray = new Array();     


          dayarray['mon'] = start.getMonth();// month
          dayarray['yr'] = start.getYear();// year
          dayarray['wday'] = start.getDay();//day of the week
          dayarray['mday'] = start.getDate();// day of the month

         if ((count % 7) == 0) {

                                document.write(' </tr><tr>\n');
                        }

                if ((count < (dayarray['wday'])) || (dayarray['mon']!=month)) {

                        document.write ('<td style=\"background-color: white; text-align: center; width: 33px;padding:2px; \" >&nbsp;</td>\n');

                } else {
                        document.write(' <td style=\"background-color: white; text-align: center; width: 33px;padding:2px; \">' + dayarray['mday'] + '   </td>\n ');
                         day +=1;

                }

}
document.write(' </tr></h6></table>');
}
function next(c){
    document.getElementById(c).style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById((c-1)).style.visibility="hidden";

}
```

**And the Html:**

```
<div style="display: block;">
                <img src="style/rightArrow.jpg" onclick="var it=12;next(it);it++;"/>


        <br/>
        <div id="calendar" style="margin:auto;width:220px;height:182px;" >
            <div id="11" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:400px;visibility: visible;">
    <script type="text/javascript">var ha=0;d=new Date();document.write(calendar(d.getMonth()+ha));</script>
    </div>

    <div id="12" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:400px;visibility:hidden;">
    <script type="text/javascript">var ha=1;d=new Date();document.write(calendar(d.getMonth()+ha));</script>
    </div>

    <div id="13" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:400px;visibility:hidden;"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">var ha=2;d=new Date();document.write(calendar(d.getMonth()+ha));</script>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Second question:**

why does the calendar only advance one month?

Comment: A programmer's ability is to reuse other code in order to save time and money. Why not reuse some other premade code on the internet rather then reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Don't wrap the TR's in <h6> it's improper html and the browser may do some very funky things in trying to figure out what you mean. Use CSS to style those pieces. For performance I would suggest generating an html string that you then replace into another element using .innerHTML. That being said if you look at the place where the "undefined" occurs in the source what do you see around it?

Comment: 1.  I'm just playing around  2.  Thanks I fixed the <h6>'s

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies in the `document.write()` that you wrap around each of your function calls.

```
<div id="calendar" style="margin:auto;width:220px;height:182px;" >
            <div id="11" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:400px;visibility: visible;">
    <script type="text/javascript">var ha=0;d=new Date();calendar(d.getMonth()+ha);</script>
    </div>
```

Remove them from around the call to calendar and you don't get the undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/qXARb/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  TO fix the second question I just had to make "it" a global variable